# Writing bitstrings to a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, bitset, bitstring

I am working on a compressor which compresses text files using Huffman coding in C++. After I perform the encoding, I get a bitstring(assume arbitrary length or say length = 2611) which represents the encoded file. Now, I want to write this bitstring to a binary file. How can I do this? Can bitset be of some use?

I am aware of the fact that the file size has to be integer number of bytes, so I will pad the bitstring to make the length a multiple of 8.

I saw some other related questions but they used pre-determined size bitset. In my case the bitstring can be quite long.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I would only want to write to a binary file, not a text file, otherwise it will make no sense to encode.

EDIT1: take for example the bitstring - "10010101010010101010101011101100001001000101011110110101001010101001001010110101"
Length is 80 that wld mean 10 bytes. I want to write these 10bytes into a binary file. How can I do this beginning with the bitstring?

Comment: In terms of actual C++ code, what is a "bitstring"?  How will it be represented?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie by bitstring I meant I have a binary string. A string with all characters either 1 or 0.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am storing it as a c++ string.

Comment: You have to convert it to bytes. Then write those to the file.

Comment: BTW: All files are binary on my computer. ;)

Comment: @dratenik Could you please elaborate how?I think I can do it by reading 8 bits at a time, but is there any shorter way using built-ins?

Comment: The hardcore way would be using bit shifts etc. The bitset could be useful for doing some of the heavy lifting, stuff 8 bits at a time into a `std::bitset<8>`, call `.to_ulong()` on it, cast the result to `unsigned char` and you have one byte of the output...

Comment: @dratenik That surely is one way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this example respond to your question, in terms of writing bistsets into a file?

As far as i know, you can write `bitset` directly to a file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>

int main ()
{
  std::ofstream ofs ("testfile", std::ofstream::out);
  std::bitset<16> foo; // not intialized
  std::bitset<16> bar (0xfa2);
  std::bitset<16> baz (std::string("0101111001"));

  std::cout  << "foo: " << foo << '\n';
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar << '\n';
  std::cout  << "baz: " << baz << '\n';

  ofs << "foo: " << foo << '\n';
  ofs << "bar: " << bar << '\n';
  ofs << "baz: " << baz << '\n';
  ofs.close();
  return 0;
}
```

This code would output in the console:

```sh
foo: 0000000000000000
bar: 0000111110100010
baz: 0000000101111001
```

and the same output in the file `testFile`

Comment: Sadly, this won't work in my case. Correct me if I am wrong, if I use bitset of size 8(or any other fixed size) and initialize it with the bitstring(the way you did for baz) it will clip the bitstring to that many bits, therefore I will lose my encoded bits.

Comment: Thanks for your question and comment. Could you provide an example of input/ouput you would like to allow the community to help you please? You may edit your question and add an example

Comment: Added an example bitstring.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your example. What do you input to your program and what do you need as an ouput. I don't understand: "How can I do this beginning with the bitstring?"

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I'm doing the exact same thing.

After you check a character in your Huffman codes and take bitstring from it you would want to do something like

```
ofstream encoder(outputFilePath, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
```

This ofstream has the proper flag to write binary strings.

after that you'd just have to write the output to a file.

Comment: The OP appears to need help with writing the bits, not just opening a binary file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).